# Probability of dot product of two vectors being odd.

Tags: probability

This was a question which was asked in an exam yesterday, and I am typing this from my memory. So I apologise in advance in case there is any error.

> Consider that $a$ is a non-zero vector, such that $a \in \{0,1\}^n$, and $b$ is a vector which is chosen uniformly and randomly from $\{0,1\}^n$.
>
> What is the probability that $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}a_i \, b_i$ is odd?

My attempt was as follows:

When choosing $b$, the total possible cases can be $2^n$. For selecting the favourable ones, if the sum of products till the $n-1^{th}$ term is odd, the last element of $b$ will be zero and if it is even, we can split it into two cases - if the last element of $a$ is zero, then we cannot choose any value of $b$ and if the last element of $a$ is one, then we can choose the last element of $b$ as one to get an odd sum. But post this, I haven't been able to conclude what should be the final answer.

Is this line of thinking correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\mathcal E$ denote the set of vectors $b$ that yield an even dot-product, and let $\mathcal O$ denote the set of vectors that yield an odd dot-product.  I claim that there is an invertible (so injective and surjective) function $f:\mathcal E \to \mathcal O$.

Alternatively, we can produce an invertible function $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ such that $f(b) \in \mathcal O \iff b \in \mathcal E$.

---

Another approach: note that if $a_i = 0$, then changing $b_i$ doesn't affect the resulting dot-product.

So, we could count the number of $b$ that produce an odd sum as follows: let $i_1,\dots,i_k$ be the indices such that $a_{i_1} = \cdots = a_{i_k} = 1$ and the rest of $a$'s entries are zero.  We can uniquely construct every vector $b$ with an odd sum as follows:

- Select the $n-k$ entries of $b$ that don't matter ($2^{n-k}$ possibilities)
- Select a vector $(b_{i_1},\dots,b_{i_k})$ for which $\sum_{j=1}^k b_{i_j}$ is odd.

It suffices to count how many choices there are for this second case.  In other words, it suffices to consider the smaller problem in which $a = (1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to think along these lines. 

Could you be kind enough to also let me know should the answer be, so that it'd help me "reverse engineer" my way to the solution, in case I get stuck? (I ask because I've been stuck at this problem since last night.)

Comment: @Gokul Sure. The answer is $1/2$, which I think is pretty clear once you understand my hint.

Comment: @Gokul added a description of another approach; see my latest edit.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Very Nice explanation. Thank you...